# Kafka streams keep logging 'Discovered transaction coordinator' after a node crash (with config StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE_V2)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka(kafka_2.13-2.8.0) cluster with 3 partitions and 3 replications distributed in 3 nodes.

A producer cluster is sending messages to the topic.

I also have a consumer cluster using Kafka streams to consume messages from the topic.

To test fault tolerance, I killed a node. Then all consumers get stuck and keep poping below info:

```
[read-1-producer] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=streams-app-3-0451a24c-7e5c-498c-98d4-d30a6f5ecfdb-StreamThread-1-producer, transactionalId=streams-app-3-0451a24c-7e5c-498c-98d4-d30a6f5ecfdb-1] Discovered transaction coordinator myhost:9092 (id: 3 rack: null)
```

what I found out by now is there are sth relevant to the configuration of StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE_V2, because if I change it to StreamsConfig.AT_LEAST_ONCE the consumer works as expected.

To keep the EOS consuming, did I miss any configuration for producer/cluster/consumer?

Comment: have you solved this issue?